# ASP.NET MVC Passing a List of Lists to the ViewBag

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

I have an Entity with a definition of:

```
public class Skill
{
    public enum Level { Begginer, Intermediate, Advanced }
    public int Id { get; set; }
    [Display(Name ="Skill Group")]
    public string SkillGroup { get; set; }
    [Display(Name ="Skill Name")]
    public string Name { get; set; }
    [Display(Name ="Level")]
    public Level SkillLevel { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Certificate> Certificates { get; set; }

}
```

In my controller I am trying to Group all the Skills by the SkillGroup Property of the Class

```
        public async Task<ActionResult> Index()
    {


        var groupedSkills = (from s in db.Skills
                             group s by s.SkillGroup).ToList();
        ViewBag.GroupedSkills = groupedSkills;                   
        return View();
    }
```

This Part works perfectly now when in the View I am trying to process this:

```
@foreach (var skillGroup in ViewBag.GroupedSkills)
{
    <h1>@skillGroup.Key</h1>
    foreach (var item in skillGroup)
    {
        <h2>@item.Name - @item.SkillLevel </h2>
    }

}
```

I get an error saying:

```
'object' does not contain a definition for 'Key'

Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code. 

Exception Details: Microsoft.CSharp.RuntimeBinder.RuntimeBinderException: 'object' does not contain a definition for 'Key'

Source Error: 


Line 46: @foreach (var skillGroup in ViewBag.GroupedSkills)
Line 47: {
Line 48:     <h1>@skillGroup.Key</h1>
Line 49:     foreach (var item in skillGroup)
Line 50:     {
```

But when I debug I can clearly see the property Key on the list of skillGroup do I need to cast it somehow? Do I need to make skillGroup a non-anonnymous type?
[ScreenShot of the watch for the Variable](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XNcQP.png)

Comment: where is you seelct after group by clause

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can solve this by following way.

The result of the group by LINQ query will be dynamic and each of its items are considered as an object when accessed at the view. That's why you see that error.
The solution to this would be convert the result of group by LINQ query to Dictionary as following.

```
var groupedSkills = (from s in db.Skills group s by s.SkillGroup).ToDictionary(x => x.Key, x => x.ToList());
ViewBag.GroupedSkills = groupedSkills;
```

The dictionary is now collection of  KeyValuePair objects where Key is the SkillGroup and Value is the list of Skills.
You can render the values of this as following.

```
@foreach (var skillGroup in ViewBag.GroupedSkills)
{
    <h1>@skillGroup.Key</h1>
    foreach (var item in skillGroup.Value)
    {
        <h2>@item.Name - @item.SkillLevel </h2>
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks man! 
Worked like a charm.
Sorry I can't give you a +1 not enough rep :(

Comment: No worries.. I am glad that you could resolve the issue.